# Fb.api posting undefined on as wall post

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, undefined

I want to post the value of an HTML id as the message on my Facebook wall. Posting to Facebook works but FB ends up writing undefined as the value pass in for message:. I am using `var word = document.getElementById("fb-root").value;` to get the value but `fb.api` is turning the value into undefined.

Please see code below:

```
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function postToWall() {
       var word   = document.getElementById("fb-root").value;
       var params = {};
       params['message'] = word;
       params['name'] = 'test';
       params['description'] = 'test';
       params['link'] = 'asas.com';
       params['picture'] = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--jbgq-gytJQ/URaJHK_93LI/AAAAAAAAAF0/SkyoK7H3r7U/s1600/Simple+Apple.png';
  params['caption'] = 'test';

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
      } else {
        alert(word);
      }
    });
  }
  </script>

 <div id="fb-root">test</div>
  <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
  appId : 'test', 
  status : true,
  cookie : true,
 xfbml : true, 
  oauth : true
 });
  };
 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
 (function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
 </script>
 </head>
        <body>
     <div id="fb-root">tests</div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
    FB.init({ 
      appId:<fbapp-id>, cookie:true, 
      status:true, xfbml:true
    });
    </script>
        <fb:login-button perms="publish_stream">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
        <a href="javascript:postToWall()">Post To Wall</a>
       </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById("myWord").value

needs to be changed to

document.getElementById("myWord").innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

After checking the code (it's messed up) you need to pay attention to these points,

**Everything is duplicated**

- In HTML, you can't have more than one element with an `id`, here you have 2 elements with `id` `fb-root`

  ```
  <div id="fb-root">test</div>
  ```
- You're loading the JS-SDK 2 times, once in asynchronous;

  ```
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
  ```

  and other in synchronous (using `<script>`)

  ```
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  ```
- You calling `FB.init()` twice
- You put one of `fb-root` element in `head` tag, it's a sin in HTML ;)
- `<div id="fb-root"></div>` is removed from the DOM when you instance the Facebook app, it's like a dummy element but important for Facebook, not you or me, you should always leave it and not use it, instead create a new element with a different `id` like `myWord`
  `<div id="myWord">my word</div>` though `div` are not inline element which makes a bad practice.

Here's your cleaned code;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function postToWall() {

                var word   = document.getElementById("myWord").value;
                var params = {};
                params['message'] = word;
                params['name'] = 'test';
                params['description'] = 'test';
                params['link'] = 'asas.com';
                params['picture'] = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--jbgq-gytJQ/URaJHK_93LI/AAAAAAAAAF0/SkyoK7H3r7U/s1600/Simple+Apple.png';
                params['caption'] = 'test';

                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
                  if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured');
                  } else {
                    alert(word);
                  }
                });

            }
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId  : '{App_id}', 
                    status : true,
                    cookie : true,
                    xfbml  : true, 
                    oauth  : true
                });
            };
            // Load the SDK Asynchronously
            (function(d){
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
            }(document));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <fb:login-button perms="publish_stream">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
        <a href="javascript:postToWall()">Post To Wall</a>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: that didn't fix the issue